# How to add focus to textbox if this empty in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have function to check if `$_POST['fbhoaczalo']` is null will show notice and focus to this field if user leave with blank.

I add this code to function.php but seem not work. I check this javascript load after  tag and not working.

```
function customised_checkout_field_process()
{
// Show an error message if the field is not set.
if (!$_POST['fbhoaczalo']) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Need enter this field') , 'error'); ?>
    <script> 
        function setFocusToTextBox(){
            var textbox = document.getElementById("fb_zalo");
            textbox.focus();
            textbox.scrollIntoView();
        }
    </script>
<?php
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this code throw any action hook provided by Woocommerce, It's depend where and how you want to run this code. like if you want to run / fire this code by woocommerce order place button then you have to use this action hook i think woocommerce_checkout_order_processed. I'm not 100% sure you may search which hook fire on place order click

Comment: I add this action after hook: `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'customised_checkout_field_process');`

Comment: isn't happening anything? maybe you can write exit() in the top of your function and see if stop the process while place order or you may look at the network tab is there any Response